# Image flip when popup window is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, magnific-popup

I'm using Magnific Popup script. I'm adding an effect to the popped up image to make it flip on entry. I add this by adding a jquery class in the `beforeOpen` event of Magnific Popup. The problem is, if I click on an image first, the flip won't happen. The image will just popup. But on close, the image will flip. If I open the same image for the second time, the flip will happen.

Here's the code I used :

```
$(function() {
    $('#gallery').magnificPopup({
      delegate: 'a',
      type: 'image',
      removalDelay: 500, //delay removal by X to allow out-animation
      titleSrc: 'title',
      callbacks: {
        beforeOpen: function() {
        // just a hack that adds mfp-anim class to markup
        this.st.image.markup = this.st.image.markup.replace('mfp-figure', 'mfp-figure mfp-with-anim');
        this.st.mainClass = this.st.el.attr('data-effect');
        },
      },
     closeOnContentClick: true,
     midClick: true // allow opening popup on middle mouse click. Always set it to true if you don't provide alternative source.
   });
  })
```

Looks like to apply the effect, the image must be loaded. The image is loading only after the first load. How can I fix this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wvveY/4/ Please refer this

Comment: Thanks but I need to flip image after the zoom effect.

Comment: Can you share the html

Comment: I got 3d unfold(flip) effect from here http://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/GAIkt